# Show next/prev if more than one post

Tags: wordpress

A little lost - believe I'm almost there though. I'm trying to make it so the next and previous links don't show unless there is more than one post.

```
<?php if($numberofposts != "1") : ?>
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hopefully it's just something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: please show the code for how $numberofposts is determined

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted.  It lacks a bit of info that would be helpful, but the fact that is tagged "WordPress" should enable anyone experienced with WP to answer the question in a helpful way.

Comment: I posted an answer, then deleted it because OP is asking for code that checks whether there is MORE than one post. Wordpress has a built-in function for checking if there is a next or previous post, not if there is more than one. Also, OP's code is missing the bit that shows how the check is currently being done.

Comment: vlasits got it. Sorry for lack of info, figured tagging it as wordpress would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if $numberofposts contains a number (instead of a string).  It probably does.  If so, you will want to rewrite your code like this:

```
<?php if($numberofposts > 1) : ?>
  <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If it doesn't contain a number, you should probably rewrite whatever function it's pulling from so that it does.

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly! After you see what it should be, it makes sense.